# Method as Condition in While Loop

Tags: php, wordpress

Need to create a Method like WordPress's function `have_posts()` for templating.

Method goes something like this:

```
class posts{
    public function have_posts(){
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM posts';
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    }
}
```

Using the class in the template (theme):

```
$posts = new posts;
while($row = $posts->have_posts()){
    echo $row['post_title'];
}
```

But I am trying to achieve something like:

```
<?php while(have_posts()){ ?>
<h1><?php post_title(); ?></h1>
<?php } ?>
```

Alternatives & Suggestions are also welcomed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific question, the following should work

```
class posts
{
    private $_result;
    private $_current;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM posts';
        $this->_result = mysql_query($query);
    }

    public function have_posts()
    {
        return ($this->_current = mysql_fetch_array($this->_result));
    }

    public function post_title()
    {
        echo $this->_current['title'];
    }
} 

<?php $posts = new posts(); ?>

<?php while($posts->have_posts()){ ?>
    <h1><?php $posts->post_title(); ?></h1>
<?php } ?>
```